# Job filter icon alignment issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design

Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab) and you should see this:

[image]

I was going to add a fee-hand circle for effect, but I didn't want to detract from the beautiful alignment of that cog.

Found on Chrome latest and also reproduced on Edge and Firefox.

Comment: +2 for find. -1 for lack of free-hand circle

Comment: Good find! Fixed and headed out in the next build :)

Comment: @AaronShekey feel free to add an answer of some form and i'll close this off.